# Why did Python claim "No such file or directory" when opening a file in "a+" mode?

Tags: python, linux, file, append

I found this in my error logs today. Why would an "a+" file open operation fail? Permissions aren't actually supposed to be an issue here, because, the user with the python process has ownership of the *export_path*.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [... omitted ...]
  File "exporting.py", line 131, in run
    f = open(fullpath, 'a+')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/export_path/export_file.xml'
```

To be clear, yes, the directory exists; it's in Linux; and, the ownership chain looks like root -> user -> user -> user (ie: "user" can actually do whatever they want with that folder). This has been proven by successfully doing:

```
touch /export_path/some_brand_new_file
```

Also, doing `vim /export_path/export_file.xml` as user is fine, too.

Comment: Does the directory you expect to contain the file already exist?

Comment: Since you haven't given any details whatsoever about OS, filesystem, anything else using the file, what the permissions and ownership settings are, whether it ever worked, if it happens often, etc. we can only make wild guesses. So I guess SELinux stopped you. Second guess *"permissions aren't actually supposed to be an issue"* but they actually are an issue.

Comment: go to the folder that the python file is in, and try to `vi /export_path/export_file.xml`

Comment: what is `export_path`?

Comment: It seems like an obvious question, but do the file permissions allow writing by the user running the program?

Comment: ```export_path``` is just a directory that's owned and writable by user. Permissions have been tested, yes.

Comment: I was speaking of permissions of the file itself, not the directory. Are you saying the file doesn't yet exist when you attempt to open it?

Comment: Right. The file itself is also okay for its permissions. It seems like this was a total fluke that wasn't quite a fluke. I dunno... maybe something else locked the file, thus causing the equivalent of a permissions problem?  Or maybe, at exactly the time the open was attempted, the permissions really were wonky?  I'm hoping it's the latter, but was wondering if there's any of of the "something locked it away" that I wasn't aware of being possible in Linux (admittedly, I'm not sure what rules exist around open files, at the moment).

Comment: Is there any code getting executed prior to `f = open(fullpath, 'a+')` that sandbox the whole process?

Comment: Well, there's a whole lot of stuff wrapping it up so that I eventually get the output logged when it raises that exception; was that what you meant by sandboxing?